# COUNTIFS using multiple criteria in single formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Column A has **`Apples`**,**`Oranges`**, **`Pears`** multiple times.
Column B has the **`count`** against them (note, some of these may be blank).

I'm looking for a formula to count just **`Apples`** and **`Oranges`** where their **`count`** is neither blank nor **`0`**.

I tried the formula below, but I get the count of **`Apples`** only:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A21,{"Apples","Oranges"},B1:B21,">0")
```

Comment: can you just sum the two `countif` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use your formula in a sum function like this:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A1:A21,{"Apples","Oranges"},B1:B21,">0"))
```

The reason is, that your function creates an array with the counts of apples and oranges respectively. You have to sum the elements in this array to get your desired result.

Comment: @pnuts select all the text in formula then press F9 to see the array.