# Multi-conditional COUNTIF()

Tags: excel

On a countif() how do I add to the formula below Not Empty on the same column?

```
=COUNTIF('Total Attempted'!E:E,"<>"&"Low Risk")
```

Excel doesn't like:

```
=COUNTIF('Total Attempted'!E:E,"<>"&"Low Risk",'Total Attempted'!E:E,"<>"&"")
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19261289/countifs-using-multiple-criteria-in-single-formula

Comment: use `COUNTIFs` instead `COUNTIF`, like this: `=COUNTIFs('Total Attempted'!E:E,"<>Low Risk",'Total Attempted'!E:E,"<>")`

Comment: Agreed - although `COUNTIFS` is only available in Excel 2007 or later - for earlier versions try subtracting the number of "Low Risk" entries from the total count of entries, i.e. `=COUNTA('Total Attempted'!E:E)-COUNTIF('Total Attempted'!E:E,"Low Risk")`

Answer (score 0):

There are signs elsewhere OP uses Excel 2010, so for the sake of an answer and courtesy of @simoco:

```
=COUNTIFS('Total Attempted'!E:E,"<>Low Risk",'Total Attempted'!E:E,"<>")
```