# Using countif to count items on differnt date

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, countif

**In one sheet I have:**
**
Column A: has ranges of dates from 4/21/14 to 5/12/14

**In another sheet I have:** 
A1: 4/25/2014

In B1 I want to count sum # of days on 4/21, # of days on 4/22, # of days on 4/23, # of days on 4/24.

I saw this post and think this is exactly what I want but the arry formula isn't working for me. 
[COUNTIFS using multiple criteria in single formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19261289/countifs-using-multiple-criteria-in-single-formula)

I remembered to press shift+alt+enter at the end but still doesn't work.

This is what I tried to put in the cell:

> =SUM(COUNTIF(column A, {A1-1,A1-2,A1-3,A1-4}))

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You want the number of occurrences of each of those dates on the first sheet listed inside of one cell?

Answer (score 0):

UNTESTED. I suggest:

```
{=SUM(COUNTIF(A:A,Sheet2!A:A))}
```

in `one sheet` with the dates of special interest in cells in ColumnA of `another sheet` (assumed Sheet2 above).